# ImageView size is very small after using a taken photo as source

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, android-camera

I'm trying to create an app that is accessing the camera when a button is pressed, and after the photo is taken, to display it on the screen, and then be able to find the color of the selected pixel.

Somehow, the photo displayed is very small, and the x,y are displaying colors even if i am selecting a pixel that is not from the image. 
I tried to change the layout's height and width to a specific value, and the photo is pixelated, even if the resolution of the photo is quite big.

I want to be able to correctly display the pixel color from the image only, not outside of it, and the image to be well-scaled on the screen.

Here is my code, hope you guys can help me, I'm a newbie. Thank you a lot!

MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView touchedXY, invertedXY, imgSize, colorRGB;
ImageView imgSource1;
Button b;
static final int CAMREQUEST = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    touchedXY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xy);
    invertedXY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.invertedxy);
    imgSize = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.size);
    colorRGB = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colorrgb);
    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMREQUEST);
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMREQUEST) {
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imgSource1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.source1);
        imgSource1.setImageBitmap(image);
        imgSource1.setOnTouchListener(imgSourceOnTouchListener);
    }
}

OnTouchListener imgSourceOnTouchListener
        = new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();
        float[] eventXY = new float[]{eventX, eventY};

        Matrix invertMatrix = new Matrix();
        ((ImageView) view).getImageMatrix().invert(invertMatrix);

        invertMatrix.mapPoints(eventXY);
        int x = Integer.valueOf((int) eventXY[0]);
        int y = Integer.valueOf((int) eventXY[1]);

        touchedXY.setText(
                "touched position: "
                        + String.valueOf(eventX) + " / "
                        + String.valueOf(eventY));
        invertedXY.setText(
                "touched position: "
                        + String.valueOf(x) + " / "
                        + String.valueOf(y));

        Drawable imgDrawable = ((ImageView) view).getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imgDrawable).getBitmap();

        imgSize.setText(
                "drawable size: "
                        + String.valueOf(bitmap.getWidth()) + " / "
                        + String.valueOf(bitmap.getHeight()));

        //Limit x, y range within bitmap
        if (x < 0) {
            x = 0;
        } else if (x > (bitmap.getWidth() - 1)) {
            x = bitmap.getWidth() - 1;
        }

        if (y < 0) {
            y = 0;
        } else if (y > (bitmap.getHeight() - 1)) {
            y = bitmap.getHeight() - 1;
        }

        int touchedRGB = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

        colorRGB.setText("touched color: " + "#" + Integer.toHexString(touchedRGB));
        colorRGB.setTextColor(touchedRGB);

        return true;
    }
};
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#00ffffff">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/xy"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="touched position: "
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/invertedxy"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="inverted touched position: "
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/size"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="drawable size: "
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/colorrgb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="touched color: "
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/source1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Take Picture"
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code may be its work fine

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView touchedXY, invertedXY, imgSize, colorRGB;
ImageView imgSource1;
Button b;
static final int CAMREQUEST = 1;
Uri fileUri;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    touchedXY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xy);
    invertedXY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.invertedxy);
    imgSize = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.size);
    colorRGB = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colorrgb);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            fileUri = null;
            fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mediapath.getPath(), "Image" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg"));
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMREQUEST);

        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMREQUEST) {
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), fileUri);
        imgSource1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.source1);
        imgSource1.setImageBitmap(image);
        imgSource1.setOnTouchListener(imgSourceOnTouchListener);
    }
}

OnTouchListener imgSourceOnTouchListener
        = new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();
        float[] eventXY = new float[]{eventX, eventY};

        Matrix invertMatrix = new Matrix();
        ((ImageView) view).getImageMatrix().invert(invertMatrix);

        invertMatrix.mapPoints(eventXY);
        int x = Integer.valueOf((int) eventXY[0]);
        int y = Integer.valueOf((int) eventXY[1]);

        touchedXY.setText(
                "touched position: "
                        + String.valueOf(eventX) + " / "
                        + String.valueOf(eventY));
        invertedXY.setText(
                "touched position: "
                        + String.valueOf(x) + " / "
                        + String.valueOf(y));

        Drawable imgDrawable = ((ImageView) view).getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imgDrawable).getBitmap();

        imgSize.setText(
                "drawable size: "
                        + String.valueOf(bitmap.getWidth()) + " / "
                        + String.valueOf(bitmap.getHeight()));

        //Limit x, y range within bitmap
        if (x < 0) {
            x = 0;
        } else if (x > (bitmap.getWidth() - 1)) {
            x = bitmap.getWidth() - 1;
        }

        if (y < 0) {
            y = 0;
        } else if (y > (bitmap.getHeight() - 1)) {
            y = bitmap.getHeight() - 1;
        }

        int touchedRGB = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

        colorRGB.setText("touched color: " + "#" + Integer.toHexString(touchedRGB));
        colorRGB.setTextColor(touchedRGB);

        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: mediapath isn't declared, also "intent" isn't declared, so I get compilation errors! Also in the onActivityResult method, we got "Bitmap bitmap..." and then imgSource1.setImageBitmap(image). "image" shouldn't be "bitmap"?